# Install Jammer build path

Tags: installation, jammer

I'm having a problem in getting the installer to pickup the build path. I need to give the Components to File group via command line. How can I give the source file path while building the .mpi file?

Any help will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jammer may refer to, [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/)